# PUN Unity - Missing a valid InstantiationId on view when manually instantiated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a procedural dungeon in Unity and I am using PUN. I am trying to spawn items that have a photon view in the scene. The walls and everything are done by seed its just interactable items. You can imagine that I dont want to have links to my resource folder for every items since I have A LOT of items. So I am trying the manual instantiation as described at the bottom of this page https://doc.photonengine.com/zh-tw/pun/current/manuals-and-demos/instantiation . The problem is when I try to destroy an item I get this error:

```
Failed to 'network-remove' GameObject because it is missing a valid InstantiationId on view: View (0)106 on MoneyPileBig(Clone) (scene). Not Destroying GameObject or PhotonViews!
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
NetworkingPeer:RemoveInstantiatedGO(GameObject, Boolean) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:3336)
PhotonNetwork:Destroy(GameObject) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PhotonNetwork.cs:2744)
NetworkDestroyer:RPCNetworkDestroy() (at Assets/Scripts/Photon/NetworkDestroyer.cs:17)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
NetworkingPeer:ExecuteRpc(Hashtable, PhotonPlayer) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:2891)
NetworkingPeer:OnEvent(EventData) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:2484)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PeerBase:DeserializeMessageAndCallback(Byte[])
ExitGames.Client.Photon.EnetPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
PhotonHandler:Update() (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PhotonHandler.cs:157)
```

Here is my code minus the stuff that puts stuff in the list since that is quite a lot of code and it is not relevant.

```
private List<PhotonInstantiatingInfo> toPhotonInstantiate = new List<PhotonInstantiatingInfo>();

private void CustomInstantiate(GameObject _prefab, Vector2 _position, Quaternion _rotation, Transform _parent)
{
    if (_prefab.GetComponent<PhotonView>() != null)
    {
        toPhotonInstantiate.Add(new PhotonInstantiatingInfo(_prefab, _position, _rotation, _parent));
    }
    else
    {
        Instantiate(_prefab, _position, _rotation, _parent);
    }
}

private class PhotonInstantiatingInfo
{
    public GameObject Prefab { get; private set; }
    public Transform Parent { get; private set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; private set; }
    public Quaternion Rotation { get; private set; }

    public PhotonInstantiatingInfo(GameObject _prefab, Vector2 _position, Quaternion _rotation, Transform _parent)
    {
        Prefab = _prefab;
        Parent = _parent;
        Position = _position;
        Rotation = _rotation;
    }
}

private void InstantiatePhotonObjects()
{
    if (!PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient) { return; }
    for (int i = 0; i < toPhotonInstantiate.Count; i++)
    {
        int newViewId = PhotonNetwork.AllocateSceneViewID();
        myPhotonView.RPC("RPCPhotonInstantiate", PhotonTargets.AllBufferedViaServer, i, newViewId);
    }
}

[PunRPC]
private void RPCPhotonInstantiate(int _index, int _viewId)
{
    PhotonInstantiatingInfo instantiationInfo = toPhotonInstantiate[_index];
    GameObject newPlayer = Instantiate(instantiationInfo.Prefab, instantiationInfo.Position, instantiationInfo.Rotation) as GameObject;
    PhotonView[] nViews = newPlayer.GetComponentsInChildren<PhotonView>();
    nViews[0].viewID = _viewId;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by manually destorying the object with an RPC. So first I would let an RPC do a PhotonNetworkDestroy if it was the master but now I don't do a PhototnNetworkDestroy but I do a normal destroy and I don't check if it is the master.